# How can I display the column ID in the django-admin users table?

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I show besides the columns username, email, first name, last name, staff user a 5th column with the users ID. I think I have to write some code into admin.py like:

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

admin.site.register(CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take advantage of `ModelAdmin.list_display`, docs here --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

```py
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'id')
    readonly_fields = ('id',)

admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

---

In case you incur in an `AlreadyRegistered` error, you should add the following **prior to your `admin.site.register`** line

```py
admin.site.unregister(User)
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting a TypeError: 'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable

Comment: admin.site.register must have 2 arguments, I've forgot the model, @Jagjeet Singh edited my answer, check it out now.

Comment: Thanks but than I'm getting this error:  django.contrib.admin.sites.AlreadyRegistered: The model User is already registered

Comment: That's because the User model is already registered into the admin by admin.contrib.auth, check my update in the response to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name',....., 'user_id']
    class Meta:
        model = User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Add user_id field in your list display it will show.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I would like to contribute.

When I tiried the accepted solution, I realized that some functionality is lost with the User admin page (Maybe other functionalities added later on). Here is the solution for whom do not want to loose other functionalities:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

admin.site.unregister(User)

# Register your models here.
@admin.register(User)
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ("id",)

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        super().__init__(model, admin_site)
        self.list_display = ("id",) + self.list_display
```

I used the default UserAdmin class and inherited from it. Than adding `"id"` field to the super's `list_display` field solved it elegantly.

Note that solution can be improved by using `AUTH_USER_MODEL` if you are using custom user class.